# Haskell: rotating image 90

Tags: haskell

I've Created an image using lists of type string. So they kind of look like this

```
pic 1 =  
["xxxx",   
 "x   ",   
 "xxx ",  
 "x   ",  
 "xxxx"]
```

So i'm trying to create a 90 degrees rotation (clockwise). This is the code i have so far, it seems to work too a level but not properly on all images.

```
rotateLine90 :: Pic -> Int -> [Char]     
rotateLine90 pic n = reverse [line!!n | line<-pic]

rotate90 :: Pic -> Pic  
rotate90 pic = [rotateLine90 pic i | i<-[0 .. (length pic) - 1]]
```

any ideas on how to improve the code.

Comment: You probably shouldn't assume that the image is a square.

Comment: `rotate90 = reverse . transpose`. Or, if you want to rotate clockwise, `transpose . reverse`. (This is not only more concise, it's also much more efficient – no indexing – and will work even on non-rectangular “images”, though the result probably won't be what you want then.)

Comment: **rotate90 = reverse . transpose** - - worked well. Thank you.

Comment: BTW this is an application of group theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works

```
rotate90 = (map reverse .) $ foldr (zipWith (:)) $ repeat ""
```

usage:

```
> rotate90 ["XXXX", "X   ", "XXX ", "X   ", "XXXX"]
["XXXXX","X X X","X X X","X   X"]
```

Comment: @chi - I like it!  I'll make the change.

Comment: the images already exist in a Haskell program and a defined 'pic :: Int -> Pic'. I am using the function on them. usage: rotate90 (pic 1) etc.

Comment: Are you sure that's a rotation? `(foldr (zipWith (:)) $ repeat "") ["ABCDE","P   F","O   G","N   H","MLKJI"] =
["APONM","B   L","C   K","D   J","EFGHI"]`

Comment: @pigworker - you are correct, I added a reverse to fix things.